# Understanding FetchType.Lazy, force in JPQL query (OpenJPA)

Tags: jpa, persistence, jpql, openjpa

I have an Entity like this:

```
public class Configuration {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @Element(name = "user_id", data = true, required = false)
    private Users users;
}
```

What I would like is to define a query where one time the LazyLoading is performed, and another time not.

But the query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getNondeletedConfiguration", query = "SELECT c FROM Configuration c  "
                     + "LEFT JOIN c.users users WHERE c.deleted = false"),
```

Does NOT load the Users into the object.

The way to force loading the users object is to access the attributes somewhere in the code. However this is not working, I don't want this behaviour. I would like to control the lazy loading only based on my JPQL statements. I don't want openJPA to magically load objects because it detects an access through a get method somewhere in the Java Code.

I guess this is a common issue and I simply misunderstand something.
However, I can't find docs about the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the `fetch` keyword to load the association:

```
select c from Configuration c left join fetch c.users where c.deleted = false
```

Note that the name `Users` for an entity representing one user is really badly chosen, and very confusing. Same for the field name `users`. You should remove the final `s`, which makes every reader think that a configuration has many users.

Comment: Thanks I found this article, but you are damn right :) http://eubauer.de/kingsware/2011/02/10/override-fetch-type-in-jpql-queries/ Is there also a way to prevent a ManyToOne relation to be fetched at all? In another query I would like the ManyToOne relation to be not fetched (even if there might be somebody calling "getUser(s)"). Is there are similar way to tell openJPA in a JPQL query to NOT fetch an object ?

Comment: No. If you want that, use a DTO, not an entity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer JB, unfortunately the naming convention with the "s" at the user is a design error that is very old and hard to fix.